# How to redirect to page after click on login button in dnn7

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I want DNN to redirect to a custom login page when the login button is clicked.

Right now it's opening the DNN login popup. Please tell me how we can have this redirect to a different page instead. Do I have to make a change in the database or somewhere in code?

Comment: Can you be more specific???

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom (new) page and place the Account Login module on that page.

Then set that as the Login Page in the Admin/Site Settings options, then when someone clicks on login they will be taken to that page to login.